# Issue is render method. 'Check the render method of `EducationBlock`.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In EducationBlock I am getting the following error:

```
react-dom.development.js:56 Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `EducationBlock`.
```

This is how I am importing

```
import EducationBlock from './EducationBlock';
```

This is how I am exporting

```
class EducationBlock extends Component {...}

export default withStyles(styles)(EducationBlock);
```

Comment: do you have more than one exports in './EducationBlock' component ?

Comment: No there is only one export

Comment: @Amnahkhatun can you post your code in js fiddle or codesandbox.io. or if you can share the code for EducationBlock.js and the importing js file. Seems like a typo

Comment: Check this out I have added
https://jsfiddle.net/amnahkhatun/3djy57c0/1/